# SharePoint 2013 - Failed to create data - new/first install

Tags: 2013, configuration

Current setup: Server 2012 in virtual environment:

- SharePoint 2013
- Stand alone version with SQL 2008 R2 Express
- All updates through windows update are installed
- All prerequisites installed without issue
- SharePoint 2013 and updates installed
- Everything has been run under a local admin account and all files were run as administrator.

I have searched high and low and can not find an answer.  Many have referenced the Analytics_*** folder which has not been created yet on the server.  Some say it is created in step 8 I am assuming my configuration does not get that far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This error/failure has been occurring through two setups.

Some of the error messages...

[image]

```
08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  ERR                      Task evalprovision has failed with an unknown exception 

08/24/2016 15:05:31  1  INF                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image

08/24/2016 15:05:31  1  INF                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  ERR                      Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.EvalProvision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  ERR                      An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.EvalProvision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Found value in collection for key global

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Found command global in collection

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Found value in collection for key initialize

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Found command initialize in collection

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function Command.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Found value in collection for key SINGLESERVER

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Found parameter SINGLESERVER in collection

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Leaving function Command.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function Command.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Found value in collection for key upgradesessionid

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Found parameter upgradesessionid in collection

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Leaving function Command.this[string key]

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                      Entering function TaskBase.OnTaskStop

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Creating the OnTaskStop event for task evalprovision

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  ERR                        Task evalprovision has failed

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        friendlyMessage for task evalprovision is An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        debugMessage for task evalprovision is An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.EvalProvision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                        Entering function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Firing the OnTaskStateChanged event for task evalprovision

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Entering function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                              Resource id to be retrieved is EvalProvisionTaskDisplayName for language English (United States)

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                              Resource retrieved id EvalProvisionTaskDisplayName is create sample data

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:evalprovision TaskBase.State:stopped

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Entering function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                              Incremented the number of tasks failed to 1

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Leaving function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Task evalprovision has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Leaving function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                          Entering function PsconfigBaseForm.TaskStateEventHandler

08/24/2016 15:05:31  18  INF                            Invoking the UI thread with the task state chagne event

...

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                          The task driver event indiated that the task driver is stopping, so we will sleep an extra 1 ms so 
things don't go too fast for the user

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                        Leaving function PsconfigBaseForm.TaskDriverEventHandler

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                      Leaving function TaskDriver.FireOnTaskDriverEvent

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                    Leaving function TaskDriver.OnTaskDriverStopping

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                  Leaving function TaskDriver.ExecuteTasks

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  ERR                  One or more configuration tasks has failed to execute

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                  Entering function TaskDriver.Stop
08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog for language English (United States)

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                      Resource retrieved id PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog is Configuration of SharePoint Products 
failed.  Configuration must be performed in order for this product to operate properly.  To diagnose the problem, review the extended error information located at {0}, fix the problem, and run this configuration wizard again.

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  ERR                    Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed in order for this product to operate properly.  To diagnose the problem, review the extended error information located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_8_24_2016_15_2_49_903_692747981.log, fix the problem, and run this configuration wizard again.

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is PostSetupConfigurationFailedUserMessage for language English (United States)

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                      Resource retrieved id PostSetupConfigurationFailedUserMessage is Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.  For further details, see the diagnostic log located at {0} and the application event log.

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                    Entering function TaskDriver.OnTaskDriverStop

08/24/2016 15:05:31  8  INF                      Sending a task driver stop event: TaskDriverEventArgs.EventCriticalityType error, TaskDriverEventArgs.EventType.stop, Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.  For further details, see the diagnostic log located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_8_24_2016_15_2_49_903_692747981.log and the application event log.


08/24/2016 15:05:32  1  WRN                                      The number of failed tasks reported by the driver is 1.
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I am at a complete loss

Answer (score 0):

here is another workaround for this error, Please make sure the

- AppFabric Caching Service is running on the SharePoint Server.
- SQL Server Agent Service is running on SQL server.

After that Run this `psconfig.exe -cmd Configdb Create SkipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost`

[Sharepoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard Error : Failed to create sample data](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-2013-products-configuration-wizard-error-failed-to-create-sample-data/)

Another thing, i would try to create the config and Admin db via PSconfig like this.

```
psconfig.exe -cmd configdb -connect -server <Server_name> -database <Database_name> -dbuser <DOMAIN\username> -dbpassword <password>
```

https://sharepointadminwiki.wordpress.com/tag/initial-farm-config-using-psconfig/